# Is there anyway to arrange objects order?

Tags: collections, outliner

Suppose I want to bring an object to the front, similar to bringing a layer to the front in Photoshop. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to have a certain object always displayed in the foreground, you can activate the option "In Front" under *Object Properties > Viewport Display*.

[image]

...Of course, this solution works only in the viewport and not in the final rendering.

Comment: .. unless you're using the Workbench renderer.. (it turns out.) I thought there might be a viewport / render distinction, but no.